# Vertices from a collection of halfspaces in 3D

Tags: 3d, geometry, computational-geometry

Can anyone suggest any good algorithms, or their own approach, to calculating the vertices of a collection of halfspaces in 3D?  The halfspaces are guaranteed to be convex and bounded.

So far web searching has been rather fruitless, `qhull` can perform this operation but I was hoping to get a more mathematical slant on the problem, rather than read masses of source code - but it is a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all halfspaces are defined by a plane with everything 'behind' the plane (ie, relative to a directed normal vector) being outside of the halfspace and everything on or in front of the plane being inside, the most obvious solution is:

- for every pair of planes get and store the line intersection;

That'll give you a collection of lines. Then for each line and plane pair:

- if the line rests exactly on the plane, do nothing;
- if the line intersects the plane and is not yet a line segment, turn it into a line segment that runs up to the point of intersection;
- if it was already a line segment and intersects the plan, clip off the part behind the plane;
- if the line was already a line segment and rests entirely on one side of the plane then do nothing.

Then collect the set of all line segment endpoints.

Comment: I was afraid this might be very expensive, but after looking at the maths it isn't really.  The few other more 'exotic' solutions I found were much more mathematically complex without being much faster.

Comment: @cmannett85 do you remember any of the other methods you read on?